# tab delimited file data to be stored into data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, csv

I'm reading in a tab delmited file into c++ and I want to manipulate the data.  I was wondering what is a good data structure to store it in.

Here is my tab delmited file:

```
Account No.  Name  Address      Available Balance
15           Ted   20 John St.  100
30           John  30 Ted St.   200
50           Roy   55 Roy St.   520
```

I want to  modify the fields in the text file, based on what commands I do.  Say I want to withdraw 50 from Ted, I would need to find Ted's account, look at the available balance and subtract 50 from it, then save it back into the text file.

Is there an efficient way to do this?  All I can think of is a long and convoluted way.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store it into an internal data structure? You might be better of using a database server like mysql. If you don't want a full fledged database, you can use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather store your data in-memory as a `vector` of Account `struct` instances. Then modifications take place on this container. Read and write to tab-delimited file only when needed, e.g. on starting and ending the program.

Comment: that definitely sounds more efficient, i think the only aspect i would have to implement is an good searching algorithm. say if i wanted to delete a whole account number, id delete the whole row. thanks for your input